# can i use ios static lib in android

Tags: android, ios

I have built IOS Static Lib i was going to redo that in java for andriod  but then i found this link which complies the .cpp  to android

http://tariqzubairy.wordpress.com/2012/03/09/arm-binaries-static-library-for-android/
and

http://tariqzubairy.wordpress.com/2012/03/12/use-of-prebuild-static-library-compiled-with-android-toolchain/

has any one tried to use a static lib for ios in andriod app ?

Comment: .cpp is c++, so it isn't iOS only, so it might be possible

Comment: Your question is answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042705/cross-plattform-use-of-a-static-a-library-on-ios-and-android-possible-what-ab

Answer (score 1):

The primary reason for using JNI here, in my view, is not for any performance benefit but for recycling a large, tested code base and multiplying the benefit of your test time. If you're only interested in performance, or your code base is not "large", you do have the option to port it to Java if that saves you considerable time.

Still, you can certainly use C++ via [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface). For example, you can compile C++ to an .so library and import the library. It's not trivial to do all of this, you need to feel comfortable with at least two languages (C++ and Java), using the command line, compilers, and following instructions. You'll also have to write some JNI code which is not that pleasant, but luckily can be recycled if you're passing from Java to C++ back to Java each time.

Some references that might come in handy:

http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html
http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/intro.html#wp9502

Set aside at least an afternoon to take this on and work through it. Definitely read the manual, don't cut any corners. You'll need to be patient with this if it's your first time, but it does work out well.